# How to deploy a small rails app with Phusion Passenger

Tags: apache, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

Although there is an overwhelming amount of information on deployment out there, I'm very confused at the moment. But maybe you can help me!

I have an existing Rails app that I want to deploy.

My (Server) Setup:

- Rails 3.2
- VPS (Linode)
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Apache
- Phusion Passenger

Everything is now installed and configured right, but how do I get the existing app to the server. FTP, Github? Capistrano seems more difficult to me.

It's just a small app, what would be the easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub would be great if it's an open-source app, or if you have an account with GitHub and private repos available.  Capistrano is likely overkill.

You can use scp (http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) if your source code is on a linux or OSX laptop.  FTP would also work... Depends on your needs really.

In all my projects, all my code goes through some kind of source code control, ie SVN or Git, so that I'm always sure my latest changes are in the repository.  Then, should I have to make a quick tweak on the deployment box, I can just check those changes back into the source code system, and pull them on my local system.  If you use scp or ftp to push the code, any changes on the server need to be copied *back*, and that's very error prone.

Comment: Good luck Kent, and don't forget, if you found this answer useful/correct, please remember to accept it.  Thanks!